# In rails, how does the self-generated primary key work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In app/views, I want to show some attribute of courses on my webpage and I coded like below:

```
  <% @courses.each do |course| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= course.code %></td>
      <td><%= course.name %></td>
      <td><%= course.description %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Drop', "/drop/#{course.id}", class: 'btn btn-primary', method: :post %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

The thing is, in the third row, no matter I use 'course.code' or 'course.id', on my webpage, it will always show the CODE of the course but not the self-generated 'id'.
I have set the primary key of table 'course' with:

```
self.primary_key = "code"
```

but I did not drop the self generated primary key 'id'.
So why can I still use 'course.id' to show course CODE?

Comment: Have you updated the database to set the column `code` as the primary key, or are the changes only in the Ruby code? Primary key changes will most likely also need to be done in the database.

Comment: Yeah, the changes are only in Ruby codes. But if the primary key has not changed in database, why can I show course code by using course.id?

Comment: Because the id column that was generated when you ran `rails g model` or jsut `rails g migration` adds the id column as the primary key serial. You reset the primary key to another column, but the id column is still there in the db and its a serial column, so it will auto increment automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you do `self.primary_key = "code"` it calls the `primary_key=` method and set the `@primary_key`

```rb
def primary_key=(value)
  @primary_key        = value && -value.to_s
  @quoted_primary_key = nil
  @attributes_builder = nil
end
```

[source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/98a57aa5f610bc66af31af409c72173cdeeb3c9e/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb#L115)

when you call `course.id` it uses `@primary_key` as attribute name

```rb
# Returns the primary key column's value.
def id
  _read_attribute(@primary_key)
end
```

[source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/98a57aa5f610bc66af31af409c72173cdeeb3c9e/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb#L18)

so when you do `course.id`, its calls `_read_attribute` with `'code'` as an argument which will return value for `code`

to get the actual id, convert the course to a `hash`

```rb
course.attributes['id']
```